# A sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that has no Cauchy subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

> Give an example of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ which has no subsequence which is a Cauchy sequence.

I can find out a sequence that is not a Cauchy sequence such as $\{\ln(n)\}$ once $|\ln(n)-\ln(n+1)|=0$ but $|\ln(n)-\ln(2n)|=|\ln(\frac{1}{2})|>\epsilon$
$\forall \epsilon<\ln(\frac{1}{2})$

I can still find a subsequence of the type ${\ln(2n)}_{2n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $|\ln(2n)-\ln(2n+1)|=0$

**Question:**

What should I do to get a sequence that has no Cauchy subsequence?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the first place, you should *only* be looking at sequences which are not convergent, right?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by $|\ln(2n)-\ln(2n+1)|=0$?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take $a_n=n$. Then for any subsequence $n_k$, $|n_k-n_{k-1}|\geq 1$. So, it has no Cauchy sub-sequence.

Answer (score 13):

Take a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n\to \infty$. Then each subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ is such that $a_{n_k}\to \infty$ and thus can't be Cauchy since necessarily Cauchy sequences are bounded.

Answer (score 11):

Take the sequence $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ It has no Cauchy subsequence since the distance between any two distinct terms is at least $1$.

Answer (score 8):

As Foobaz John says, any sequence with $a_n\to\infty$ works, and it's easy to see that $|a_n|\to\infty$ is also sufficient. In fact this latter condition is necessary and sufficient. If $|a_n|\not\to\infty$, then by definition there is some $c>0$ for which there are infinitely many values $n_i$ such that $|a_{n_i}|<c$ for each $i$. Now by Bolzano-Weierstrass the subsequence $a_{n_i}$ has an infinite subsequence $a_{n_{i_j}}$ which is convergent, and therefore Cauchy.

Comment: Ah, Bolzano-Weierstrass, also known as the theorem about subsubsubscripts.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't understand your analysis but sequence $a_n = \ln n$ doesn't have  Cauchy subsequence since its limit is $\infty$

Comment: I guess this one uses the theorem that every Cauchy sequence converges

Answer (score 1):

Bolzano-Weierstrass: Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Fact: Every convergent sequence is bounded.

Strategy: Try an unbounded sequence.

Guess: $a_n=n$

Conclusion: (I leave it to you)